# Mac OS X Yosemite connectivity issue

Tags: terminal, network, ping

Every so often my MacBook Pro starts getting very intermittent network connectivity. I have a Virgin Media SuperHub.

Pinging my router gives me lots of request timeouts:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2438 ttl=64 time=2.000 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2439 ttl=64 time=33.810 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 67976
Request timeout for icmp_seq 67977
Request timeout for icmp_seq 67978
Request timeout for icmp_seq 67979
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2444 ttl=64 time=1.568 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2445 ttl=64 time=1.633 ms
```

Sometimes the timeouts last only a few pings sometimes many.

Through experimentation I've found that flushing the arp cache using

```
sudo arp -a -d
```

Immediately max ping start working but then after a bit the timeouts come back. I've confirmed this by doing:

```
sudo watch -n 1 arp -a -d
```

And the ping timeouts disappear and I can browse without any slowness as long as I leave that running.

Rebooting the computer also clears this problem for a while but it comes back.

I need a permanent fix for this.

Comment: Are there any console messages that happen when the drops arise? Look for discoveryd or sharingd if you think AirDrop or Continuity are active when the normal traffic drops. Also, can you be sure there isn't interference? Guessing the cause might be hard, so perhaps we can answer how to troubleshoot this and once you have the cause nailed down, the fix is often trivial.

Comment: Nothing in console about discoveryd or sharingd.  There is
`25/02/2015 10:33:49.638 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.viber.osx) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.`
That's running a lot.
I don't think it's interference because no other computers including 4 other macs have this problem.
I just find it intriguing that clearing the arp cache fixes the problem temporarily.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

http://www.macstadium.com/blog/osx-10-9-mavericks-bugs/

Even if supposedly only applies to Maverick, I found a Macbook with Yosemite having the same problems and the fix seemed to work. Worth a try.